# How to update identity if any change occur directly in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I did some updates in user table in database directly.
Now when i run application and get user, it is not getting new updates and checking from old data

```
var user = UserManager.Find(username, encryptPassword);
```

It is returning null on giving new username.

Please guide me how to refresh identity if we made any change directly to database

Comment: what was your database..??

Comment: Mysql is my database

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following when there is changes to a user which needs to update the identity claims:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: true, rememberBrowser: false);
```

Comment: Hey. On first line it is returning me null. I have applied your code

Comment: That's because it can't find the user for the userId you supplied.

Comment: thats what the issue is, its updated in database but not getting in application. I updated directly in database and now getting from application. but application is checking in old data. I don't know how it will get new data

Comment: `FindByIdAsync(userId)` does a db lookup, are you sure that the userId you are trying exists in the database? Also check that the application is actually using the correct database.

Comment: I have added this:

**(await UserManager.FindAsync(username, encryptPassword);**

But it is returning null in my case and if i check with old values, its working fine

Comment: If I remember correctly the Find methods does a direct db lookup, so they should find the user after a change, unless you are changing the user id?

Comment: I have only changed password, old password is not encrypted and now new password is encrypted. so there is only change in password field. When i checked encrypted password it is returning null, when old form password it is getting the user.